# Why won't my level 4 Campfire increase temperature?

Tags: dont-starve, reign-of-giants

I didn't play RoG for some time and I noticed that now in some nights my campfire does not increase the temperature of my character and neither do the thermal stones I dropped next to it. The four screenshots below show a whole night, I made sure the fire is always on Level 4, but the temperature stays the same. Also, I experienced nights where I almost froze to death while standing near a campfire..

Did they change something or is this a bug? Do you experience the same?

[image: Campfire]

Comment: [This Steam post](http://steamcommunity.com/app/219740/discussions/0/34095132042575295/) has some potential solutions. The user who asked the question said restarting the game fixed it for him.